# IntelliJ idea associate file type with no extension

Tags: intellij-idea, file-type

How to associate files with no file extension (linux default file type) somehow that IntelliJ idea recognizes as HTML and highlights everything just as simple .html file?

I have a Java project where templates are written in default file type, witch contain a lot of HTML and javascript. I don't want to edit them as plain text - as it is now.

Comment: do you have just one file or many? if many do they all have different names?

Comment: I have a lot files and all have different names. I would like to set up so that all files with no extension is associated with html format.

Comment: You can try and edit ~/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/config/options/filetypes.xml
It will be faster than adding it one by one from the UI. This file content will look a little like so: http://pastebin.com/n8HJCC00

Comment: just fyi for me this file was at ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017.3/options, took a bit of rooting around to find